# Google Geocoder Returning null From Reverse Lookup

Tags: geocoding, reverse-geocoding, google-geocoder

I am trying to use the Google geocoder to do a reverse-geocoder lookup.  I am running the exact same command on 8 values, and I am only having an error on two of them, which has me confused as one of the failing values is identical to one of the working values.  (The 'working' values aren't really working- they still return a value of undefined from the 'formatted_address' field, but they aren't throwing errors).  The command that I am running is as follows:

```
geocoder.geocode({latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(machineList[i].y, machineList[i].x)}, function(results, status) { address = results[0]; });
```

I am receiving a type error from Javascript, claiming that results is null.  I'm not sure why this is happening.  Any ideas?

Comment: What specific values are causing null to be returned?

Comment: got it- the lat/long are  38.1471977000  -97.4348983000.  The error is now coming from the line where the value is used- 'data += address.formatted_address'.  Don't ask me why- I have absolutely no clue. Although now I'm thinking it is a timing issue- if I insert an alert before the address value is actually used, there is no error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it turns out this was a timing issue.  The geocode() command was taking longer to complete for certain locations than for others, which caused the value to show up as null.  I ended up eliminating the problem by moving all the subsequent code into the callback function (I hadn't done this earlier because the whole thing is running inside of a loop, and I was having some difficulty getting it to pass in the iterator as a parameter).  Now everything seems to be working well and the locations are showing up as they should.